# Двоятся сообщения почты (связка debian vimbadmin)

Tags: postfix

В vimbadmin настроил для ящика второй алиас, чтобы двум людям уходили сообщения. Какое-то время это работало нормально, но с какого-то момента второму стало приходить по два одинаковых сообщения.
Как это продиагностировать и устранить проблему.
Заранее благодарен

Comment: "Как это продиагностировать" - посмотреть по журналам почтового сервера что куда шлётся. Кроме вас псевдонимы мог кто-нибудь изменить?